# A book about a world cut off, heiress raised as a pleasure girl, and broken A.I

Tags: story-identification, novel, artificial-intelligence

Got the title from a list of fairly new authors about 6 years ago (around 2010ish). The main character is raised to be a prostitute/geisha as an orphan. Turns out she is the last person left of a "noble" house. The Houses are all derived from their function to the original colony and her ancestors were the techs in charge of the A.I. and they damaged it to help the others stage a coup for control of their area. She is being hunted to prevent her from messing with the status quo as the colony is cut off from the rest of the galaxy by the sabotaged A.I. Part of what makes the Houses able to keep power is that their abilities are programmed into their genes, and that is why she is a threat, as she could still repair the damaged A.I. just by being what she is.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188150/sci-fi-novel-about-a-reptilian-assassin-and-a-hacker-kid (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

The book is called [Palace](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1342802.Palace__The_Pinch___1_) by [Katherine Kerr](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/44003.Katharine_Kerr) and Mark Kreighbaum

Thanks everyone for your help. I didn't remember the author because I associate her with fantasy not sci fi.

Comment: Can you explain why the answer matches? And you can accept your own answer.